# Turtle draws a curve

Tags: python, math, turtle-graphics

I have a textfile with x and y coordinates that I with this program want to calculate a curve with, however, the outcome is a straight line repeating itself
The data is imported separately as x and y coordinates. Here is the code that would handle this data

```
def plotDots(t,x_acc,y_acc):                       
    while x_acc and y_acc:
        t.pu()
        t.goto(x_acc[0],y_acc[0])
        t.pd()
        t.stamp()
        x_acc, y_acc=x_acc[1:], y_acc[1:]

def plotRegression(x,x_acc,y_acc):
    ave_x=sum(x_acc)/len(x_acc)                     #Calculating curve
    ave_y=sum(y_acc)/len(y_acc)
    n=len(x_acc)
    m=((x_acc[0]*y_acc[0])-(n*ave_x*ave_y))/(x_acc[0]**2-(n-x_acc[0]**2))
    y=ave_y+m*(x-ave_x)
    return y

def main():
    t=turtle.Turtle()
    wn=turtle.Screen()
    turtle.setworldcoordinates(-1000,-1000,1000,1000)
    doc=open("labdata.txt")
    line=doc.readline()
    y_acc=[]
    x_acc=[]
    while line:
        values=line.split()
        x_acc=x_acc +[float(values[0])]
        y_acc=y_acc +[float(values[1])]
        line=doc.readline()
    plotDots(t,x_acc,y_acc)
    for x in x_acc:
        t.goto(x, plotRegression(x,x_acc,y_acc))

    doc.close()
    wn.exitonclick()

main()
```

Comment: Why not use `for line in doc` to iterate over the lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I read your script, you're fitting a linear line to the data. You are then drawing that *fit*, the *linear* line, since `plotRegression` will return the value fitted value `y` that belongs to your input `x` (in `t.goto(...).
So it's wonder you see a straight line; you should see that.

Simple use

```
for x, y in zip(x_acc, y_acc):
  t.goto(x, y)
```

to draw your curve.

---

Note: it makes more sense to calculate the regression once, and then evaluate it for every x. So make a function `calcRegression` that returns `a` and `b`, your fitted parameters, and then a `evalRegression` that takes input `x` (either a float or an array of floats) and returns `y`.
I wouldn't call a function `plotRegression` if it actually doesn't *plot* anything.

---

If you are going to use this for scientific calculations, you're better off using numpy/scipy/pandas for the calculations, and e.g. matplotlib for the plotting.

If it's just part of practice, no problem, but don't use it for real-world problems, since people have solved this before (and overall, more carefully and more detailed).